# Should I use a three-way associative table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, erd

I have a scenario which I believe I have come up with a solution - however, I can't be sure it's a manageable one, or even correct. The scenario is as follows.

There are are three tables involved in this: `groups`, `user_types`, and `resources`.

The requirement is that a *user* can add a *resource* for a specific combination of *user types* and *groups*. For instance, a given user might upload a ‘technical manual’ (`resources`) that is supposed to be only accessible to ‘painters’ and ‘foremen’ (`user_types`) in ‘group a’ (`groups`). They might then assign the ‘manual’ to only ‘painters’ in ‘group b’, and so on.

My tentative solution to this is to have a many-to-many (M:N) relationship between `groups` and `user_types` using an associative table called `groups_user_types`. Then, that associative table has a many-to-many relationship to `resources`, using another associative table unfortunately called `groups_user_types_resources`. I've also considered having an associative table that *connects* the three tables, but I'm not a DBA and I don't even know if this is a valid way to do it.

Next problem is seeing if my chosen ORM supports this type of relationship, but that's a question for another Stack Exchange site...

Does this relationship make sense? Is there a solution that doesn't *connect* an associative table to another table?

If I have not provided enough information, please let me know and I'll explain further.

Answer (score 2):

If I have followed correctly, the two options is whether to have one or two intermediate table for the relationship between groups, user_types and resources. The answer, from a purely design point of view depends on whether that relationship is a strong or weak one. In other words, if `groups_user_types` (lets call it `authorizations`) is something that should exist if one of the other entities do not, and if an authorization is shared between resources or not. Let's see an example:

"manual1" can be accessed by:

- painters in group a
- foremen in group a
- painters in group b

manual2 can be accessed by:

- painters in group a
- foremen in group a

  ```
  resources
  ---------
  id|name
   1|manual1
   2|manual2

  user_types
  ----------
  id|name
   1|painters
   2|foremen

  groups
  ------
  id|name
   1|a
   2|b

  groups_user_types
  -----------------
  id|group_id|user_type_id
   1|       1|           1
   2|       1|           2
   3|       2|           1

  groups_user_types_resources
  ---------------------------
  resource_id|groups_user_type_id
            1|                  1
            1|                  2
            1|                  3
            2|                  1
            2|                  2
  ```

You know your application better than I do, but I do not see `groups_user_types` as a strong entity (no attributes, no reasons to exist if  `groups_user_types_resources` disappears). Maybe I am wrong, and permissions is a big part of our application, and you will give each resource a named authorisation that can be shared between resources. But if not, you can change the last two tables into:

```
    groups_user_types_resources
    ---------------------------
    resource_id|group_id|user_type_id
              1|       1|           1
              1|       1|           2 
              1|       2|           1
              2|       1|           1
              2|       1|           2
```

Again, this depends on how strong `groups_user_types` is and if those permissions are shared between resources or not. Are the permissions for resource 1 the same entity that the same permissions for resource 1. Will you have lots of resources with the exact same permissions? Are there permissions that won't be allowed? Only you can answer that.

Comment: Group A might only have painters while group B might have both painters and foremen - you can set which user_types can be used by each group. Then, when you create a resource, you can specify which user_types in each group can use it. So I think I need the two tables. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question is really about relationships of degree 3, sometimes called "ternary relationships".  There is a diagram [here](https://www.dlsweb.rmit.edu.au/toolbox/ecommerce/tbn_respak/tbn_e2/html/tbn_e2_devsol/er_model_relnshps.htm) that illustrates a ternary relationship between course, subject, and teacher.

Whether such a three way relationship exists or not in your case depends on your subject matter, and your analysis of it.

A three way association table allows you to express a three way relationship.  Such a thing can  certainly be done.  The fact table in a star schema often serves as the hub in a multidimensional relationship.  Whether this meets your design goals or not depends on what you are trying to do.